# Is there a frequency to which electromagnetic radiation would make an entire ice cube (or another material) vibrate?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, water, ice

Microwave oven radiation makes water molecules rotate. I just wonder if there is a wavelength, supposedly related to the lattice of water ice, molecules spacing, whatever, that would set the entire cube into motion.
Actually if it works on other materials, I am also interested.

Comment: I think you need to better define "vibrate" and "in motion" because technically, every molecule in the ice cube is put into motion by the microwave. For example, are you looking for something which would put the entire mass in motion in phase (the whole mass moving/vibrating in the same directions)?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a frequency that can set the center of mass of the cube in motion?